# Нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки "назад" в браузере редиректило на google.com

Tags: javascript

Есть сайт с формой, после заполнения которой и нажатия ігиьше происходит редирект на новую страницу confirm.html. Мне нужно чтобы со страницы confirm.html при нажатии кнопки "назад" в браузере перекидывало на сайт google.com. Помогите пожалуйста это сделать

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку <kbd>←</kbd> в браузере возвращается к предыдущей странице в истории, вам надо будет до перехода на новую страницу в историю добавить `https://www.google.com/`. Добавляется оно вот так:

```js
window.history.pushState({}, ``, `https://www.google.com/`);
```

---

Обратите внимание на политику. Этот метод работает безотказно для страниц от того же источника (домена), но может блокироваться браузером для остальных:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://www.google.com/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///D:/Applications/Projects/Web/Test/pages/test.html'.

Comment: Под "локальных" имеется ввиду страницы текущего домена?

Comment: @SwaD да. (просто текст чтобы я мог отправить комментарий, поскольку оно слишком короткое)

Comment: Может тогда это стоит пояснить/уточнить в ответе(а я, например, долго вчитывался в этот ответ, т.к. под локальным почему то подумалось про localhost или file:///)

Comment: @SwaD теперь как?

Comment: В целом понятнее. )